# Initrd/Initrc file of Tizen

Tags: android, linux, operating-system, tizen

I am trying to port tizen on an Android phone.

As I understand we can boot a system without an initrd image. So do we really require a initrd for Tizen?

If yes, can I reuse Android's initrd ?

Thanks,
~Rogers

Answer (score 0):

[This is how to flash an image to the phone.](https://source.tizen.org/documentation/reference/flash-device)

Unless you have a released image for that phone and you really know what you're doing I would not recommend flashing it, it can damage your phone and come over a lot of problems: you can void your warranty, you may mess up your original OS or you can experience battery overheating, etc.

Even if you would manage to install the image without having major problems you may not have the right drivers or may not be able to use that phone properly if that specific phone is not officially supported by Tizen OS.